# Using google maps' didTapAtCoordinate method in conjunction with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm noticing that:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    print("You tapped at \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")
}
```

is overriding the gesture recognizer:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
let aSelector : Selector = "tappedOnMap"
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)
mapView.userInteractionEnabled = true
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

func tappedOnMap() {
    print("Tapped")
}
```

"Tapped" never prints, but "You tapped at so and so" does.

My map view is stretched out to fill the view screen. It seems that `didTapAtCoordinate` is overriding the GestureRecognizer. (I am sure of this because when I attach the gesturerecognizer to the superview (top-most view) of that controller, and disable 'User Interaction' on the mapView, "Tapped" gets printed.) How can I have both methods be called?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working class to compare what you are doing wrong :

It might be :

1. The GMSMapViewDelegate is not called
2. MapView.delegate = self is not set
3. Missing the underscore in front of the `func mapView(**_** MapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool`

   ```
   class CustomMapPicker: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate
   {
       @IBOutlet weak var MapView: GMSMapView!

   override func viewDidLoad()
   {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       MapView.delegate = self
       let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 25.2048, longitude: 55.2708, zoom: 10)
       MapView?.camera = camera
       MapView?.animate(to: camera)
       MapView?.isMyLocationEnabled = false
   }

   func mapView(_ MapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
   {
       print("lat = " + "\(coordinate.latitude)" + " long = " +  "\(coordinate.longitude)")
   }

   func mapView(_ MapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool
   {
       return true
   }
   }
   ```